# Missing time when using timer

Tags: timers, time, speed

I have set up Timer2 to count every tick at 16MHz, or 62.5ns per tick. Then I run the following code:

```
int t = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<64;i++){
  data[4*i] = TCNT2;
  data[4*i+1] = TCNT2;
  byte now = data[4*i+1];
  byte last = data[4*i];
  t += now > last? (long)(now-last) : 256 -(long)(last-now);
  data[4*i+2] = TCNT2;
  data[4*i+3] = TCNT2;    
  }
}
for (int i=0;i<255;i++){
  Serial.println(data[i]-data[i+1]);
}
```

and I get the output: "4 4 4 11" (repeated) which makes sense, 4 clock cycles to read *TCNT2* and write it to the correct place in *data* and 11 cycles when also evaluating the loop condition. However, I can't understand when the variable *t* is updated. I have tried running with and without *t* and both give the same timings. From my (obviously lacking) understanding updating a variable is at minimum one instruction, so how can it do it under one clock cycle? Am I misunderstanding what one instruction is or does the *TCNT2* counter for the timer not update accurately here?

Answer (score 1):

Ops, I just realized it's the compiler working it's magic. I never used t, thus the compiler said "Wtf is this guy doing, this t is useless and I'll remove it!". When I used t I got sensible results.